# Proxypass to different directory / i-MSCP webmail on standard port

Tags: apache

I'm trying to figure out how to access the "Rainloop" webmail installed by the open-source panel i-MSCP on a default 443 port.

By default i-MSCP panel and webmail can only be access by https://domain.tld:4443 resp. https://domain.tld:4443/rainloop.

**But I want to access it like this: https://domain.tld/webmail**

```
SSLProxyEngine On
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /webmail https://127.0.0.1:4443/rainloop/
ProxyPassReverse /webmail https://127.0.0.1:4443/rainloop/
```

But this results in an 503 error by i-MSCP

```
ProxyPass /test http://127.0.0.1:443/
ProxyPassReverse /test http://127.0.0.1:443/
```

This test configuration works, but of course doesn't map the right location. This points to /var/www/html

May it be possible to map to `/var/www/imscp/gui/public/admin`which I assume is the correct directory?

If you have deeper knowledge of i-MSCP and know how to accomplish this task in a better way, please answer also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please just use our free plugin PanelRedirect. With this plugin, any request made on port 443 will be passed through Apache to Nginx on port 4443 transparently. Same thing for requests made on port 80.

Comment: I already knew the redirect plugin, I could also redirect via htaccess - but this doesn't solve the problem, cause some users cannot access the 4443 port, I need it on a standard 443 port.

Comment: @bortran That is exactly the purpose of the `PanelRedirect` plugin. You must use the proxy mode. Then, your customers will be able to access the panel through a common URL such as `https://panel.domain.tld` without having to specify a non-standard port. Apache will reverse-proxy to nginx behind the scene transparently.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't know that was already implemented. I'll give it a try, thanks a ton!